# Django: storing static text in models and views

Tags: django

I use django-tinycontent to store small block of text in templates but I can't find an app or a way of saving into a DB the static text from models, forms and views.

For example:

```
title = forms.CharField(
    label="Title",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': ''})
)
```

How can I save the text Title in a DB because I don't want to have to do a new release if I need to change the text for that label.

Comment: What is your use case? I.e.: how often do you expect the `label` field of your `title` field to change?

Comment: Not often I imagine but I want the client to be able to manage the text.

Comment: You could build it yourself, create a `FieldConfig` model, with fields such as `form`, `field`, `label`, `placeholder` and anything else you need. Then for each such form, populate these values for each field in the `__init__` method. For added points, make a `mixin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're building a CMS; so personally, I would prefer using an existing package like [Django CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/en/) combined with [`djangocms-forms`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-forms). Anyway, if we're building it, here's a simple way to do it:

### The Model

```
class FieldConfig(models.Model):
    form = models.CharField(max_chars=64)
    field = models.CharFields(max_chars=64)
    label = models.CharFields(max_chars=64)
    placeholder = models.CharFields(max_chars=64)
```

### The Mixin

```
class FieldConfigMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FieldConfigMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        form_name = self.__class__.__name__
        fconfig = FieldConfig.objects.filter(form=form_name)
        # for every matching form/fields, override the values
        for conf in fconfig:
            if conf.field not in self.fields:
                continue

            field = self.fields[conf.field]
            field.label = conf.label
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = conf.placeholder
            # ... and so on (more form/field config as required)
```

### The Usage

Suppose you have some forms that you want to allow overriding of field meta-info, just mix in the class above and voila, the form field is now configurable

```
class SomeForm(FieldConfigMixin, forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField(
         label="Title",
         required=True,
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': ''})
     )

# Test it out

assert SomeForm().fields['title'].label == 'Title'
FieldConfig.objects.create(form='SomeForm', field='title', label='Foo Title')
assert SomeForm().fields['title'].label == 'Foo Title'
```

***DISCLAIMER***: This is from the top of my head, I have not tested it, and this may very well fail to work completely :) just saying.

Clearly this is a very optimistical implementation, and in real life, you will probably find yourself handling one corner case after the other. Hence, my suggestion is to try and use something existing (with as many users) as I mentioned above.